# Polylines on android map disappear when zoomed out

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I am using the code below to draw a bunch of vertical lines at 5 degree intervals on a Google map (android API v2).  All works great until zooming out to approximately zoom level 5.1, at which point all my lines disappear.  Is this a bug in my code, or something that the maps API does on purpose?  How can I get these lines to show up at all zoom scales?

Thanks very much.

```
if (gMap != null)   {
            double lat = loc_service.getLatitude();
            double lng = loc_service.getLongitude();
            LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(lat-(MAP_WIDTH/2), lng-(MAP_WIDTH/2)), new LatLng(lat+(MAP_WIDTH/2), lng+(MAP_WIDTH/2)));
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 720, 720, 0);
            gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            gMap.moveCamera(cu);

            // initialize the time marker AT ONE  MINUTE INTERVALS
            time_markers = new ArrayList<Polyline>();
            // calculate distance to zero-second mark
            double offset = getLngOffset();
            for (int i=-MARK_RNG; i<MARK_RNG; i++)  {
                PolylineOptions plOptions = new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(90, (lng-offset + (i*5))))
                    .add(new LatLng(-90, (lng-offset + (i*5))))
                    .width(2)
                    .color(Color.BLUE);

                time_markers.add(gMap.addPolyline(plOptions));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug in the Google Play Services library similar to [the one I reported](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5123) some time ago.

I just tried

```
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(90, 5))
        .add(new LatLng(-90, 5))
        .width(2)
        .color(Color.BLUE));
```

and it draws a line from `0,0` to `0,5` on low zoom levels and from `0,5` to `90,5` after you zoom in. Both are of course incorrect.

A workaround would be to use `85` instead

```
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(85, 5))
        .add(new LatLng(-85, 5))
        .width(2)
        .color(Color.BLUE));
```

but don't ask me why it works correctly this way...

You may also want to add more info to the linked issue report.

Comment: Your 85/-85 fix did the job - thanks.  Maybe 90/-90 is outside the projection (i remember reading somewhere that the map itself only goes to +/- 85 degrees latitude). I'll add my problem to the bug report in the hopes of getting an answer.