# Google map v2 polylines disappear when map zoom is changed

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am adding a long polyline to connect my transit points. The line is fine when the zoom level is default but as soon as I zoom the lines disappear. This behavior is very random as some line disappear when I zoom once and some disappear on full zoom and some on medium zoom.
Few questions on SO have a solution to change the z-index but it does not work.[image: Polylines fine][image: Disappear on zoom]

Comment: unless adding the code which produces this behavior ...this only permits guessing.

Comment: Polylines drawn incorrectly in certain cases. [Google Issue 5313](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821816) Strange behaviour drawing polyline. [Issue 5123](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35822851)
Polylines which venture near the poles are drawn incorrectly. [Issue 9176](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827934) take your pick...

Comment: How about this one (v2) [Bug:Polyline disappear Google issue 35830044](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830044) ?. Are we supposed to guess what your problem **is** ? You need to provide *test cases*. (*minimum code* to **replicate** your problem). There are **MANY** more.. *unfortunately* `Polyline` is, and *always* has been *riddled* with bugs.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, here's a possible duplicate - [Polylines on android map disappear when zoomed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043763/polylines-on-android-map-disappear-when-zoomed-out?rq=1).

Try something like this, as OP suggested.

```
map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(85, 5))
        .add(new LatLng(-85, 5))
        .width(2)
        .color(Color.BLUE));
```

Comment: Hi Mac lad ;O), I come from Leek (***not*** south of Leek)   :O)